# Extracting data from multiple sqlite databases to single .csv?

Tags: sqlite, cmd

I am using this to extract data from sqlite database file, `commands.txt` are where I put my sqlite query:

```
sqlite3 base1.db < commands.txt > "base1.csv"
```

This works OK for one file, now I need to apply that commands to multiple `.db` files at once. This `.db` files are stored inside subfolders (they all have the same structure, so that sqlite command work OK for all)
I need to collect data from all `.db` files based on sqlite query in `commands.txt` into one `.csv` file, if possible?
When I execute this, I dont get result but empty file.

```
cd /D "C:\sqlite-tools-win32-x86"
for /R %%G in (*.db) do (
    sqlite3 < commands.txt > "%%~dpnG.csv"
)
```

Comment: Where is the file `commands.txt` placed?

Comment: C:\sqlite-tools-win32-x86\commands.txt

Comment: Ah, then it's not a path error. Anyway, now I spotted what's missing inside of your `for` loop: the body must read `sqlite3 "%%~G" < commands.txt > "%%~dpnG.csv"` (so the `.db` file wasn't referred to)...

Comment: I tested, it works now, thank you. Any hint how to make it so that all data is saved into one `.csv` file? For now it save one `.csv` for every `.db`.

Comment: Replace `> "%%~dpnG.csv"` by `>> "common.csv"` (and write `del "common.csv" 2> nul` just to begin a new file); note that [`>>`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) means appending while `>` means (over-)writing...